# How can I interpolate an array of alternations into a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to do:

```
@foo = getPileOfStrings();

if($text =~ /@foo(*.?)@foo/)
{
 print "Sweet, you grabbed a $1! It lived between the foos!";
}
```

What's going on here is I need a `$text =~ /($var1|$var2|$var3)(*.?)($var1.../`; I don't know how many values there are, and I don't know the values until run-time.

Array interpolation into a set of ORs seemed to be the straightforward way to do this, but it doesn't seem to work right, and I'm getting into a twisty set of code...it's all alike!

Comment: Can you show us some of the text you are trying to match? I find it hard to *extrapolate* from the regex-en.

Comment: @lexu: Good joke. Unfortuantely I'm at work and have to sanitize everything I ask for help on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) and the [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator:

```
my $strings = join "|", getPileOfStrings();
my $re      = qr/$strings/; #compile the pattern

if ($text =~ /$re(*.?)$re/)
```

If you wish for the same word to delimit the stuff in the middle say:

```
if ($text =~/($re)(.*?)\1/)
```

If the strings could contain characters that are considered special by Perl regexes, you may want to use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to prevent them from being used by the regex:

```
my $strings = join "|", map quotemeta, getPileOfStrings();
```

And, as Michael Carman points out, if `getPileOfStrings()` is not designed to return the strings in the order you desire them to be matched in, you may want to use [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to force the longest match to be first in the alternation (items earlier in the alternation will match first in Perl 5):

```
my $strings = join "|" map quotemeta,
    sort { length $a <=> length $b } getPileOfStrings();
```

Remember to sort before running quotemeta since `"a..."` (length 4) will be transformed into `"a\\.\\.\\."` (length 6) which is longer than `"aaaaaa"` (length 5).

Comment: The order of things within an alternation can be important. Unless `getPileOfStrings()` can be trusted to do it, you should sort the results by length with the longest values first.

Comment: I was mentioning that on Sinan Ünür's answer at the same time you were mentioning it on mine (which was the same time he was adding it to his post), great minds indeed.

Comment: If you two aren't careful, you'll devolve into an infinite recursion.

Comment: Definitely do use the quotemeta, unless you specifically intend to treat the strings as regexes. Why trust? Quotemeta is cheap.

And since performance was mentioned elsewhere: Perl 5.10 has a trie-izing stage in the regex engine that will optimize `(literal|literal|literal|...)` alternations. If you don't have 5.10 *and* you run into a performance problem you could look at `Regexp::Trie` or `Regexp::Assemble`, but don't do it needlessly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Regex::PreSuf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regex::PreSuf):

```
my $re = presuf(getPileOfStrings());
```

Before going ahead with this, you might want to think about what you want the following code to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @pile = qw(ar a);
my $string = 'ar5a';

my $pile = join '|', @pile;
my $re = qr/$pile/;

my ($captured) = $string =~ /$re(.*?)$re/;

print "$captured\n";
```

If you want `$captured` to contain `"r5"`, sort `@pile` by the lengths of its elements before joining as in

```
my $pile = join '|', sort { length $a <=> length $b } @pile;
```

Comment: Regex::PreSuf will result in a more efficient regex than the straight `join`, but it also looks like it might screw up lists that have been ordered to match the longest (or shortest) alternation: "The original order of the words is not necessarily respected"

Comment: @Chas. It looks like I was editing my response as you posted this comment.